# JavaScript "\r" carriage return is not working in recent version of Chrome 93.0.4577.82 while using in javaScript and encoding the URl

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Example

```
"Hello test" + "\r welcome world"
```

Current output :

```
Hello testwelcome world
```

expected output :

```
Hello test
welcome world
```

Comment: `\n` is the standard newline. However ALL whitespace is ignored in HTML. Please post a [mcve] because it is not at all clear what you mean

Comment: Did this ever work? All I can find is: use \n for newlines in console logs.

Comment: If you can show your code, you will receive more better answers, obviously.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to break lines in `JS` is, using `<br>` tag. That's the line breaking tag in `HTML`.

**Example**

```
"Hello test <br> welcome world"
```

**Here is the answer.**

```js
document.write("Hello test <br> welcome world")
```

*All the best.*

Comment: Thanks for solution! But while encoding the url to pass via https the <br> is not working. we already tried this it is just passing as it is like string not breaking the line.

Answer (score 0):

Okay! Add `%0D%0A` to the place you want to encode a line break on the URL.

- `%0D` - carriage return character
- `%0A` - line break character

**Example :**

```
"Hello test%0D%0Awelcome world"
```

Comment: Tried that aswell it is also not working :)

Comment: If you can show your code, you will get more better answers.

Comment: we are passing carriage return in the javascript code and encoding to the url.
at that point of time it is not considering the \r carriage return.
recent chrome version ignoring the \r character. till the last chrome version 86 it worked perfectly fine.